# How to expand a equation into a quadratic equation?

Tags: quadratics

I need a explanation and steps how I can expand this equation:

$$(x−p)^2+(mx+c−q)^2=r$$

into this one:

$$(m^2+1)x^2+2(mc−mq−p)x+(q^2−r+p^2−2cq+c^2)=0$$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is basic algebra. Do you understand how to expand $(x-p)^2$?

Comment: yes x^2 - 2xp + p^2

Comment: Excellent. How about $(mx+c-q)^2$?

Comment: @BabaMara $(mx+c-q)^2=((mx+c)-q)^2=(mx+c)^2-2(mx+c)q+q^2=\cdots$

Comment: ok thank for help!

Comment: Note the $r$ should not be squared in the constant term, since it has just been "moved to the left" from the starting equation.

Comment: @BabaMara Or remember this formula: $$(a+b+c)(d+e+f)=ad+ae+af+bd+be+bf+cd+ce+cf$$

$$(mx+c-q)^2=(mx+c-q)(mx+c-q)$$

$$=(mx)(mx)+(mx)(c)+(mx)(-q)+(c)(mx)+(c)(c)+c(-q)+(-q)(mx)+(-q)(c)+(-q)(-q)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is $(x-p)^2$? See:

$$(x-p)^2=(x-p)(x-p)=x^2-2xp+p^2$$

Now what is $(mx+c-q)^2$? See:

\begin{align}
(mx+c-q)^2=(mx+c-q)(mx+c-q)&=m^2x^2+mcx-mqx+mcx+c^2-cq-mqx-cq+q^2 \\
&=m^2x^2+2mcx-2mqx-2cq+c^2+q^2 \\
&=m^2x^2+2(mc-mq)x-2cq+c^2+q^2
\end{align}

Now combine:

\begin{align}
(x-p)^2+(mx+c-q)^2 &= x^2-2xp+p^2+m^2x^2+2(mc-mq)x-2cq+c^2+q^2 \\
&=(m^2+1)x^2+2(mc-mq-p)x+p^2+c^2+q^2-2cq
\end{align}

Now this equals $r$ by assumption, so we can substract $r$ on both sides and get:

\begin{align}
(m^2+1)x^2+2(mc-mq-p)x+p^2+c^2+q^2-2cq &= r \\
\iff (m^2+1)x^2+2(mc-mq-p)x+p^2+c^2+q^2-r-2cq&=0
\end{align}